# Tangent undefined for polar curves ($r^2=a^2\sin(s\theta)$)?

Tags: derivatives, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

I am considering the function $r^2=a^2\sin(2\theta)$ and am trying to find tangents perpendicular to the initial line, so $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=0.$

However, when I take the derivative by implicit differentiation, $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ ends up being divided by $x$, which is $x=r\cos\theta =\sqrt{a^2\sin(2\theta)}\cos\theta$ so it seems like any solution to the numerator of $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ being zero which is where cosine or sine are zero should be undefined.

However, in my text book, the tangent at $\theta=\pi/2$ is given as one solution, and from sketching the curve it looks to me like this should be a tangent perpendicular to the initial line?

So I was wondering why the answer is undefined, and how to deal with undefined tangents?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: By initial line I mean the $\theta=0$ line.

My calculation steps were:
$$
x=rcos(\theta)
$$
$$
x^2=r^2\cos^2(\theta)
$$
$$
=a^2\sin(2\theta)\cos^2(\theta)
$$
$$
=2a^2\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta)
$$
$$
2x\frac{dx}{d\theta}=2a^2cos^2(\theta)[\cos^2(\theta)-3\sin^2(\theta)]
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{2a^2\cos^2(\theta)[\cos^2(\theta)-3\sin^2(\theta)]}{2x}
$$
$$
=\frac{2a^2\cos^2(\theta)[\cos^2(\theta)-3\sin^2(\theta)]}{a(2\sin(\theta)(\cos(\theta))^{\frac{1}{2}}}
$$

So $\theta=\pi/2$ gives undefined $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ although it is given as a solution to $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=0$ for the tangent to be perpendicular to $\theta=0$...

Comment: Can you write out your implicit differentiation steps? I cannot see what is wrong from what you said. Also what do you mean by "tangents perpendicular to the initial line"?

Comment: ...yeah what does initial line mean?